# Java Lambda groupby reducing with transformation

Tags: java, lambda

Can someone tell me why these to lambdas don't produce similar results?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> strings = List.of("a", "bb", "cc", "ddd");

        Map<Integer, List<Character>> result1 = strings.stream()
                .map(toStringList())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(List::size
                        , Collectors.reducing(List.of(),concat())
                ));
        System.out.println(result1);

        Map<Integer,ObjStr2> result2 = strings.stream()
                .map(ObjStr1::new)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjStr1::getLen
                        , Collectors.reducing(new ObjStr2(), ObjStr1::to2, ObjStr2::doReduce)));

        System.out.println(result2);
    }

    private static Function<String, List<Character>> toStringList(){
        return s-> s.chars()
                .mapToObj(c->(char) c)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static BinaryOperator<List<Character>> concat(){
        return (l1, l2) -> {
            return Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        };
    }


}

class ObjStr1{
    String str = "";

    ObjStr1(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    static ObjStr2 to2(ObjStr1 o){
        return new ObjStr2(o.str);
    }

    Integer getLen(){return str.length(); };
}

class ObjStr2{
    String str = "";

    ObjStr2(){}

    ObjStr2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    static ObjStr2 doReduce(ObjStr2 a, ObjStr2 b){
        a.str += b.str;
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return str;
    }
}
```

Results:
{1=[a], 2=[b, b, c, c], 3=[d, d, d]}
{1=abbccddd, 2=abbccddd, 3=abbccddd}

Expected:
{1=a, 2=bbcc, 3=ddd}

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: "Can someone tell me why these to lambdas don't produce similar results?" Please show what you expect, and what they actually produce instead.

Comment: Stack Overflow says your question doesn't have enough description is a good sign that you should add some _useful_ description to your question. For example, why do you think they should produce similar results?

Comment: I think the problem is the `new ObjStr2()` in your second collector. You're using the same starting element for all groups.

Comment: but it should be an empty starter element

Comment: Wow, that is all way overkill. Try this: `Map<Integer, String> result = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, Collectors.joining()))` --- The result is `{1=a, 2=bbcc, 3=ddd}` which exactly matches "Expected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `new ObjStr2()` in your second collector. You're using the same starting element for all groups.

You're concatenating everything to the same object, and because this is mutable, everything is appended to that same object.

Instead, make your `doReduce` return a new object:

```
static ObjStr2 doReduce(ObjStr2 a, ObjStr2 b) {
  return new ObjStr2(a.str + b.str);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/j57GWw)

Output:

```
{1=[a], 2=[b, b, c, c], 3=[d, d, d]}
{1=abbccddd, 2=abbccddd, 3=abbccddd}
```

(But if you're going to do that, you may as well just use `String` directly).