# Java Lambda not compiling

Tags: java, lambda

Can someone tell why doReduce compiles but doReduce2 doesn't:

```
List<String> strings = List.of("a", "bb", "cc", "ddd");
Map<Integer,ObjStr2> result2 = strings.stream()
                .map(ObjStr1::new)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjStr1::getLen
                        , Collectors.reducing(new ObjStr2(), ObjStr1::to2, ObjStr2::doReduce)));

class ObjStr1{
    String str = "";

    ObjStr1(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    static ObjStr2 to2(ObjStr1 o){
        return new ObjStr2(o.str);
    }

    Integer getLen(){return str.length(); };
}

class ObjStr2{
    String str = "";

    ObjStr2(){}

    ObjStr2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    static BinaryOperator<ObjStr2> doReduce2(){
        return (a,b) -> new ObjStr2(a.str + b.str);
    }

    static ObjStr2 doReduce(ObjStr2 a, ObjStr2 b){
        return new ObjStr2(a.str + b.str);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return str;
    }
}
```

I can even copy the contents of doReduce2 directly into the lambda and it will compile. 
reducing is supposed to accept BinaryOperator

Comment: what is the compile error?

Comment: Incompatible parameter types in method reference expression

Comment: @Andreas he means this: return (a,b) -> new ObjStr2(a.str + b.str);

Comment: Surely you're reducing a stream of `ObjStr1`? So you can't apply a `BinaryOperator<ObjStr2>` to it?

Comment: @Andy I'm transforming ObjStr1 to ObjStr2

Comment: @RoryG please [edit] to add that code. I am still confused (following on from [my answer yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389877/3788176)) why you're not simply using `String` directly.

Comment: @Andy this not my real world problem

Comment: `ObjStr1::to2` isn't a bifunction. If you want to transform to ObjStr2s, map before reducing (e.g. with a `mapping` collector).

Comment: @AndyTurner It's a mapping function, which is what `reducing()` expects. It's `static`.

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ Java 11, maybe its a bug in intelliJ

Comment: @RoryG Sorry, previous comment was in error. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try calling the method `doReduce2` without the use of method reference and it should work -

```
Map<Integer, ObjStr2> result2 = strings.stream()
        .map(ObjStr1::new)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjStr1::getLen,
                Collectors.reducing(new ObjStr2(),
                        ObjStr1::to2, ObjStr2.doReduce2())));
```

Answer (score 1):

`doReduce()` *is* a `BinaryOperator`.

`doReduce2()` *returns* a `BinaryOperator`.

Since `reduce()` expects a `BinaryOperator`, you can give `doReduce` as a *method reference*, or you can *call* `doReduce2()`.